# awk for selection of text in a non standard formatted document

Tags: text, awk, block, repeat

first question so here we go.

I am trying to use awk to pull a selection of text out of 40 documents. Each document has unique formatting (nothing is the same length, headings are different, etc).

What I want is to do is write an adaptable awk program that I can change easily between texts. I have included a part of the most representative of all the texts. With a good answer I can adapt it to the rest. My awk skills are OK, but not good enough for some of the problems I'm encountering.

Essentially, I am using the barebones one liner:
    awk '/Subject A/{p=1} /CIP/{print;p=0}p' sample.txt

on this

```
Subject A
DISCIPLINE AREA
CIP
Code

random material

Subject A #note that this is the second instance of Subject A
UN

Description of Subject

Subject B
DISCIPLINE AREA
CIP
Code
etc...
```

I get the result:

```
The second instance of Subject A
all the way through to
Subject B
```

What I want to do:
Print/Output all of material between the first instance of "Subject A", include the second instance of "Subject A" and end just before "Subject B".

Problems:
There are hundreds of these repetitions and the only constant is that there is always a subject, discipline area and cip in a block. I cannot get the full description of the block as it starts at the second Subject B.

I've seen a lot of solutions but I cannot get them to work on mine :(

Any takers?

Sorry it is so long but I had to explain it.
-R

Comment: And I didn't know it highlighted keywords. Please treat all text as text.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) extraction job:

```
@(skip)
@  (all)
Subject A
@darea
CIP
Code
@  (and)
@    (collect)
@line
@    (until)
Subject B
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(do (put-lines line))
```

This assumes that `Subject A` and `CIP` and `Code` are literal text, but the `DISCIPLINE AREA` varies. For this reason, the entire `DISCIPLINE AREA` is captured into a variable, rather than matched with text. These details are easily adjusted. For instance if each file has a different identifier for `A` in `Subject A` and so forth.

Why we match the first `Subject A` is because `@(skip)` is nongreedy.

Also, importantly, we have an `@(all)` construct in place which matches two features in parallel. Both have to match. The `@(skip)` will skip material in the file until the point where both clauses of the `@(all)` find a match.

One branch of the `@(all)` matches a multi-line `Subject A` structure which has to have a `CID` and `Code` in the right place. For instance if `CIP` doesn't occur or is followed by junk in the same line, or is not followed by `Code`, then there is no match.

In parallel with this we have another pattern matching clause (separated by `@(and)`, in which a `@(collect) which gathers lines into a list until just before`Subject B`.

When both branches of the `@(all)` match, all we have to do is dump the collected list of lines.

A variable matched in a `@(collect)` clause automatically turns into a list of strings. To output that we just use `put-lines`.

Run:

```
$ txr extract.txr data
Subject A
DISCIPLINE AREA
CIP
Code

random material

Subject A #note that this is the second instance of Subject A
UN

Description of Subject
```

So you can see that this is a robust approach in which multiple patterns which span multi-line text work together to avoid false positives, yet it is easy to read the code six months later and still understand what it is looking for and extracting.

Suppose that a `Subject` section has to have just one out of the two: either just a  `CIP` or `Code` are fine. TXR's `fuzz` can express this nicely:

```
@(fuzz 1 2)
CIP
Code
```

This means "at least one out of the following two lines have to match".